# Get to work reindexing in external code

Tags: magento2, reindex

I've tryed to use this example (and other examples on the internet) https://webkul.com/blog/reindexing-programmatically-magento-2/ to execute reindexing programatically.

The case is I want to call reIndexing() from my custom class outside Magento 2 ([example](https://magentoexplorer.com/how-to-run-custom-code-outside-of-magento-2)), but I almost always get `"Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CronReindexer::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\\Indexer\\Model\\IndexerFactory, instance of Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager given..."`

How to solve this?

EDIT:

/main.php

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('CronReindexer');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

/CronReindexer.php

```
class CronReindexer {

    protected $indexerFactory;

    protected $indexerCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory $indexerFactory,
        \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory $indexerCollectionFactory
    ){
        $this->indexerFactory = $indexerFactory;
        $this->indexerCollectionFactory = $indexerCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function reIndexing(){
       $indexerCollection = $this->indexerCollectionFactory->create();
       $ids = $indexerCollection->getAllIds();

       foreach ($ids as $indexerId) {
            $indexer = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry')->get($indexerId);
            $indexer->reindexAll();
        }

    }

}
```

Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Create the **Reindex.php** script in the root folder and add below code in this file.

```
 use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
 require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

 $params = $_SERVER;
 $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
 $obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

 $state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
 $state->setAreaCode('frontend');

 $indexer = $obj->get('Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory')->create();
 $ids = $indexer->getAllIds();
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($ids);

 foreach ($ids as $indexerId) {
     $indexer = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry')->get($indexerId);
     $indexer->reindexAll($indexerId); // this reindexes all
     //$indexer->reindexRow($id); // or you can use reindexRow according to your need
     echo $indexerId;
     echo '<br>';
 }
 echo 'Succesfully Reindex';
```

Or for flush the Cache and Reindexing execute shell commands in php file.

```
$command = 'php /path-to-magento-root-directory/bin/magento cache:clean && php /path-to-magento-root-directory/bin/magento indexer:reindex && php /path-to-magento-root-directory/bin/magento cache:flush';
echo '<pre>' . shell_exec($command) . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $indexer = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry')->get($indexerId);
 $indexer->reindexAll();
```

try this code and make sure $indexerId is your selected index id.

Comment: I edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

This errors type occurs when you are extending a class and the child class construct does not match the parent class construct

Probably the parent class expects

```
\Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory
```

where as you have passed

```
\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager
```

**EDIT**

Why are you using object manager try to place this code loop and try

```
   foreach ($ids as $indexerId) {
       $idx = $this->indexerFactory->create()->load($indexerId);
       $idx->reindexAll($indexerId); 
    }
```

Comment: Please, check my code.

Comment: Do you get the same error still ? Have you tried clearing var/generation folder ?

Comment: Yes, the same error.

Comment: Try using IndexerFactory and remove var/cache and var/generation

Comment: Sorry for my poor knowledge, I am newbie at OOP. I've changed to your loop, but no difference. Cache cleaned.