# Magento 2 programatically reindex using custom extention controller file

Tags: magento2, custom, reindex

How to set the re-index process automatically in Magento 2 site.

We have one custom extension.
We want to set cone in controller files.
So when we run this controller URL; re-index function work.
Anyone helps me to set this functionality.

My code is here.

```
protected $_pageFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
     \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory $indexerFactory,
        \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory $indexerCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
{
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    $this->_indexerFactory = $indexerFactory;
    $this->_indexerCollectionFactory = $indexerCollectionFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('mp2_agtech_productstockupdate'); //gives table name with prefix
    $sql = "Select * FROM " . $tableName;
    $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql); // gives associated array, table fields as key in array.


    foreach($result as $updateresult){

        $agtech_productid = $updateresult['productstock_id'];
        $agtech_productqty =  $updateresult['productstock_qty'];
        $tableNameqty = $resource->getTableName('mp2_cataloginventory_stock_item'); //gives table name with prefix
        $sql = "Update " . $tableNameqty . " Set qty = ".$agtech_productqty." where product_id = ".$agtech_productid;
        echo "Quantity Update of  Product Id => ".$agtech_productid."<br/>";
        $connection->query($sql); 

    }

}

$indexerCollection = $this->$indexerCollectionFactory->create();
$indexerFactory = $this->$objectManager->get('Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory');
$indexerIds = array(
    'design_config_grid',
        'customer_grid',
        'catalog_product_flat',
        'catalog_category_flat',
        'catalog_category_product',
        'catalog_product_category',
        'catalogrule_rule',
        'catalog_product_attribute',
        'cataloginventory_stock',
        'catalog_product_price',
        'catalogrule_product',
        'catalogsearch_fulltext'
);
foreach ($indexerIds as $indexerId) {
    echo " create index: ".$indexerId."\n";
    $indexer = $indexerFactory->create();
    $indexer->load($indexerId);
    $indexer->reindexAll();
}
```

Comment: Try once maybe this help :-https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174282/get-to-work-reindexing-in-external-code/#answer-189461

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> File: app/code/vendor/module/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="router_id" id="router_id">
            <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> File: app/code/vendor/module/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\module\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
 protected $_pageFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
     \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory $indexerFactory,
        \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory $indexerCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
{
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    $this->_indexerFactory = $indexerFactory;
    $this->_indexerCollectionFactory = $indexerCollectionFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
   $indexerCollection = $this->_indexerCollectionFactory->create();
  $indexerFactory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory');
$indexerIds = array(
    'catalog_category_product',
    'catalog_product_category',
    'catalog_product_price',
    'catalog_product_attribute',
    'cataloginventory_stock',
    'catalogrule_product',
    'catalogsearch_fulltext',
);
foreach ($indexerIds as $indexerId) {
    echo " create index: ".$indexerId."\n";
    $indexer = $indexerFactory->create();
    $indexer->load($indexerId);
    $indexer->reindexAll();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: Try updated code. It's works for me

Comment: clear generated folder and retry

Comment: rm -rf  generated/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95853/discussion-between-msa-and-anil).

Answer (score 1):

```
public function reindexAll() {
    $indexerFactory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory');
    $indexerIds = array(
        'catalog_category_product',
        'catalog_product_category',
        'catalog_product_price',
        'catalog_product_attribute',
        'cataloginventory_stock',
        'catalogrule_product',
        'catalogsearch_fulltext',
    );
    foreach ($indexerIds as $indexerId) {
        echo " create index: ".$indexerId."\n";
        $indexer = $indexerFactory->create();
        $indexer->load($indexerId);
        $indexer->reindexAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: We put same but not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding **Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory** to your Controller/Model:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory $indexerFactory,
) {
    $this->indexerFactory = $indexerFactory;
}
```

And then once you want to trigger a reindex. For example for the product to category and product flat indexes. Adjust these to whichever indexes you want to reindex.

```
$reindex = array('catalog_product_category', 'catalog_product_flat');
foreach ($reindex as $index_id) {
    try {
        $idx = $this->indexerFactory->create()->load($index_id);
        $idx->reindexAll($index_id);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Do something with the exception
    }
}
```

Comment: No it not working for me.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you get an error? Is your index not reindexed? Which one are you reindexing?

Comment: We want all indexing reindex.

Comment: we put full array 'array('design_config_grid',
   'customer_grid',
   'catalog_product_flat',
   'catalog_category_flat',
   'catalog_category_product',
   'catalog_product_category',
   'catalogrule_rule',
   'catalog_product_attribute',
   'cataloginventory_stock',
   'catalog_product_price',
   'catalogrule_product',
   'catalogsearch_fulltext',
  );'

Comment: Strange, but if you want all you're better off using a more dynamic approach to begin with. Like https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193159/how-to-reindex-programmatically-in-magento2

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
namespace Ktpl\Indexing\Cron;

class Indexer
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Indexer\Model\Processor $processor
    ) {
        $this->processor = $processor;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        /* Regenerate indexes for all indexers */
        $this->processor->reindexAll();

        /* Regenerate indexes for all invalid indexers */
        $this->processor->reindexAllInvalid()
    }
}
```

> [There are two types of method for indexing](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-reindex-indexer-programmatically-in-magento-2/)

1. **Regenerate indexes for all indexes**

   $this->processor->reindexAll();
2. **Regenerate indexes for all invalid indexers. This will only regenerate for invalid indexer.**

   $this->processor->reindexAllInvalid()